# Inject real implementation of Angular's $timeout service in a Karma/Jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a small Angular service that handles asynchronous rate-limiting of other functions, similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320016/1063392).  Since the main purpose of this class is to moderate asynchronous behaviors, I'd like to be able to test this service asynchronously - I won't be able to prove that this class is working with a purely synchronous test.

If I understand correctly, when Angular's `ngMock` module is loaded, the built-in `$timeout` service is replaced with a mocked version of `$timeout` which allows tests to synchronously run functions that are ordinarily asynchronous.  However, in this case, I'd like to use the real implementation of `$timeout` instead of the mocked version.

**How can I inject the real implementation of `$timeout` into my unit test?**

Here's what my tests looks like currently (I'm writing my tests in TypeScript):

```
describe('My Tests', () => {

    let myService: MyService,
        $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        inject(($injector) => {
            // this gets me the mocked version of $timeout
            $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        });

        myService = new MyService($timeout);

        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 5000;
    });

    it('should pass', (done) => {
        $timeout(50)
            .then(() => {
                // this is never called
                expect(1).toBe(1);
            })
            .finally(done);
    });

});
```

When I run this test, Karma complains that the test too took long because the mocked`$timeout` service never actually kicks off its deferred timeout:

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: You have to use $timeout.flush() to end $timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call $timeout.flush(); to force all $timeout inside your controller to be released :

```
it('a ctrl with $timeout inside', inject(function($timeout) {
    var myCOntroller = $controller('Controller', { $scope: $scope });

    // flush timeout(s) for all code under test.
    $timeout.flush();

    // this will throw an exception if there are any pending timeouts.
    $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();

    expect($scope.result).toBe("whatIexpect");
}));

// with your example
it('should pass', (done) => {
    $timeout(50)
        .then(() => {
            // this is never called
            expect(1).toBe(1);
        })
        .finally(done);

    $timeout.flush();
});
```

Everything better [explain here](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/11/unit-testing-code-that-uses-timeout-angularjs/) :)

In addition, you should never use the real $timeout because it will REALLY slowing down your tests...

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!  While it doesn't actually answer my original question, your link showed an example of passing a millisecond timeout to the `flush()` function to allow for more fine-grained control - I was unaware that the mocked `$timeout` has this ability.  This should allow me to test my function with confidence.