# block consecutive $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I am working in an angular project there I have a grid with some data and some actions.

On clicking one of the action in onclick function an ajax request is going the server side which is once in a life time process.

But when the user consecutively click the action button before the first request's response came the same call is going to the server more than once which ends up in error.

I have tried to disable the action button before the ajax request even though I cant prevent it from multiple request. Is there any method to block the second request?

My code is

```js
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: urls.api_url_serv + 'notification/read?token=' + token,
  transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: {
    notification_id: notification_id
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  var data = response.data;
  //Some actions 

}).catch(function(response) {
  var status = response.status;

  // Some actions

});
```

```
<span ng-class="{'disabled': read_disable}">
<i class="fa fa-envelope" ng-click="MarkAsReadNotification(row.id)"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Rather than blocking the request after it has been made, have you tried debouncing the button so only one call is triggered?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320015/how-to-write-a-debounce-service-in-angularjs

Comment: @ssube I dont understand. Do you mean to disable the button? I have already disabled the button in onclick function

Comment: Disabling the button should prevent multiple requests from being sent. What is creating the second request that you want to cancel?

Comment: @ssube I think before I am disabling the button another request is sending. I mean within seconds if i click the same button same request is sending

Answer (score 0):

you can do it idiomatic way for example
(Using ES6 Syntax to use `this` in a simple way)

```
this.makeRequest = () => {
  if (!this.request) {
    this.request = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: urls.api_url_serv + 'notification/read?token=' + token,
      transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
      withCredentials: false,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: { notification_id }
    });

    this.request.success((data) => {
      // If you want let the user do a request, after this one is finished
      this.request = undefined
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable a button, use the [ng-disabled directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled):

```
<button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="disableButton">
    Submit
</button>
```

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.disableButton = true;
    return $http(config)
      .then(function(response) {
         var data = response.data;
         //Some actions 
         return response.data;

    }).catch(function(response) {
        var status = response.status;

        // Some actions
        throw response;

    }).finally(function() {
       $scope.disableButton = false;
    });
};
```

Disable the button before starting the [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Use the `.finally` block to re-enable the button when the request settles either fulfilled or rejected.

Comment: I have tried this but when we click the button within seconds its sending same request